# Order in always_comb block

Tags: system-verilog

I have the impression that in an always_comb block, all the non-blocking assignment should work in parallel. That is, if I have

```
always_comb
begin
    a = b;
    b = c;
end
```

Then, a should be equal to c regardless of the order of above two lines in the always_comb block, as they are evaluated concurrently anyway. However, today I experienced an issue that change the order of above two lines, the results are different!!! Whay is that?

Answer (score 1):

The statements within a `begin/end` block execute serially. It does not matter if you are using an `always_comb` or any other kind of `always` block. But you are using *blocking* assignments, not *non-blocking* assignments, which is the proper thing to do in an `always_comb` block. Non-blocking assignments are used to assign sequential logic, which implies storage of the current and next state.

Answer (score 1):

This difference stems from that combinational always blocks cannot "self-trigger". The way the simulator works when a signal changes value is to locate all `always` blocks with that signal in the sensitivity list, then execute them one by one sequentially. But, only if that block is not already running! In your case the expected behavior would require the block to run twice, but instead only one iteration occurs for every update of `c`.

The situation is unfortunate since the sensitivity list is a simulator concept and generally ignored altogether for synthesis. Most synthesis tools would generate a wire from your code without producing any warning, creating a simulation-synthesis mismatch.

Note that an explicit sensitivity list (e.g., `always @(b or c)`) does not make any difference. One solution is to always ensure that the assignments are in the right order. Another is to use non-blocking assignments, but this is generally advised against since it slows down the simulator. (Note that VHDL does not have blocking assignments, and would thus always have this performance penalty. On the plus side you do not have problems like this.)